# icefaces ace:fileEntry does not work

Tags: java, icefaces, icefaces-3

For my web application I would like to use the `ace:fileEntry` component.

I tried the showcase but it does not work. There is NO error. The `fileEntryListener` is never called. The file is still uploading (the browser sais) but the file is not stored on the server.

Is there any know issue with that?

```
 <h:form id="fileUploadForm">

   <h:panelGrid id="fileUploadGrid" columns="2" width="100%" styleClass="textEntryInputTable">

   <ace:fileEntry id="fileEntryComp"
                                   label="File Entry"
                                   relativePath="uploaded"
                                   fileEntryListener="#{ticketDetailListBean.listener}"/>                            

       <h:commandButton id="submit" value="Datei uploaden" type="submit" styleClass="icebutton" />

       <h:message id="msg" for="fileUploadForm:fileEntryComp" infoClass="infoMessage" errorClass="errorMessage"/>
       <h:outputFormat value=""></h:outputFormat>

     </h:panelGrid>

 </h:form>
```

The property "`fileEntryListener`" can be set to anything. It doesn`t matter, if the bean and the method are existing. If I reference to a not existing bean, no error is caused. That tells me, the Listener is never used.

I am using `tomcat 7.0.34` and `icefaces 3.2.0.` I tried my own implementation and I still copied the example of icefaces showcase. Both does not work.

Comment: Thanks for response. I tried it on a simple jsf site, which only contains the fileupload. There is no popup or menu. I am navigating to the site direct and manual. The jsf site is implemented with a template file which is communicating to other managed beans. Can that be a problem?

Comment: From the given details not able to figure out the problem, but I suggest you to check the project code/dependencies/configuration..etc., and fallow these threads... [thread1](http://www.icesoft.org/JForum/posts/list/19375.page#sthash.rg1m4T9H.dpbs), [thread2](http://www.icesoft.org/JForum/posts/list/21124.page#sthash.bkpM5QWz.dpbs), [thread3](http://www.icesoft.org/JForum/posts/list/18467.page#sthash.jeMIvbHR.dpbs), [thread4](http://www.icesoft.org/JForum/posts/list/18317.page#sthash.7winfAnp.dpbs).

Comment: I think I got the solution. Problem is that I uses Icefaces for new site implementations. But I have already struts sites. And all Sites (also Icefaces sites) are passing Struts Filter. That was still the problem..

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it solved as follow : 
check your fileEntry tag wrapped with an ace:panel

```
    <ace:panel>
    <ace:fileEntry id="signature-file-entry"
                   relativePath="/files/"
                   maxFileCount="1"
                   maxFileCountMessage="#{msg.concurrentFileUploadLimit}"
                   fileEntryListener="#{userManagement.signatureUploadListener}"
                   maxFileSize="6291456"
                   maxFileSizeMessage="#{msg.maxFileSizeMessage}"
                   maxTotalSize="18874368"
                   maxTotalSizeMessage="#{msg.maxTotalSizeMessage}"
                   required="true"
                   requiredMessage="#{msg.requiredMessage}"
                   useOriginalFilename="true"
                   useSessionSubdir="true"
                   tabindex="6"/>
    <ace:message for="signature-file-entry" showSummary="true" showDetail="false" />
    <h:commandButton value="#{msg.sendFile}" type="submit" id="uploadAFile" />
</ace:panel>
```

check your web.xml, it should contains following tags :

```
    <context-param>
       <param-name>org.icefaces.mandatoryResourceConfiguration</param-name>
       <param-value>fileEntry</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

and

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/icefaces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```